# My WebSite is being attacked, should i be worried seeing the logs?

Tags: information-gathering

Recently i just checked my server and found in logs that it is being attacked. Seeing the logs i am not able to exactly figure out, if i should actually be worried.i checked the attacker domain rating on opendns, it is not good.Follwoings are the logs of the request received:

```
31.210.102.114 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:31:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2095 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:33 +0000] "GET /w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:) HTTP/1.1" 404 54 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:33 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 41 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:33 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 41 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:34 +0000] "GET /pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 34 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:34 +0000] "GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 38 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:35 +0000] "GET /MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 38 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:36 +0000] "GET /SQL/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 34 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:36 +0000] "GET /myAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 38 "-" "ZmEu"
190.248.156.50 - - [04/Mar/2017:16:53:36 +0000] "GET /mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 41 "-" "ZmEu"
46.229.164.99 - - [04/Mar/2017:17:42:46 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 23 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl;
+http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
```

Comment: Welcome! Would you provide more detail about the hosting environment? Have you checked Wikipedia for ZmEu: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZmEu_(vulnerability_scanner)

Comment: I am not sure if i should give away hosting env info here in public, although that wouldn't be the toughest thing to know.

Comment: That information is very important. If your hosting environment is for Microsoft .NET, then requests for PHP vulnerabilities are moot.

Comment: Nothing to worry about, all got 404, except HTTP header which exactly how it is supposed to be. But you should review your overall security anyway, perhaps install some scanners yourself and do the same on your website. Here are some of the well known scanners....Wapiti(python), Uniscan, Nikto(perl), Vega(java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geoiplookup of IPs says:

```
➜  ~ geoiplookup 31.210.102.114
GeoIP Country Edition: TR, Turkey
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: TR, N/A, N/A, N/A, N/A, 41.013599, 28.954901, 0, 0
GeoIP ASNum Edition: AS197328 INTER NET BILGISAYAR TURIZM TIC LTD STI
➜  ~ geoiplookup 190.248.156.50
GeoIP Country Edition: CO, Colombia
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: CO, 02, Antioquia, Medellín, N/A, 6.251800, -75.563599, 0, 0
GeoIP ASNum Edition: AS13489 Telecomunicaciones S.A. E.S.P.
➜  ~ geoiplookup 46.229.164.99
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: US, VA, Virginia, Ashburn, 20147, 39.033501, -77.483803, 511, 703
GeoIP ASNum Edition: AS39572 DataWeb Global Group B.V.
```

The first query has the `User-Agent` [masscan](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan) which is:

> TCP port scanner, spews SYN packets asynchronously, scanning entire Internet in under 5 minutes.

`User-Agent` can be faked of course, but why would you alter it to a port scanner's UA.

The second part uses [ZmEu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZmEu_(vulnerability_scanner)) which claims to be a Romanian vuln scanner.

The third part claims to be [SemrushBot](https://www.semrush.com/bot/) and has only one query, the robots.txt. This seems legit according to its website and it doesn't seem like an attack at all.

You can block these IP addresses (there are also automated solutions for that), or you can block whole IP address ranges, there are lots of lists available for this purpose (e.g.: https://zeltser.com/malicious-ip-blocklists/).

I wouldn't be worried though, it seems like a normal background traffic. However pay attention to upgrade your software, cause they might find and exploit a vuln that is known to the public.

Answer (score 2):

Setup [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), or it's equivalent, to monitor your weblogs and **automatically block the IP address from people doing stuff like this**. Always keep an eye on your logs but have plans in place for what to do when things happen.

Every system on the Internet gets scans like these pretty much daily if not hourly in some cases. Learn how to harden your server and applications so you don't have to worry and test it with everything you can. There is a lot to doing security well but tools like [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) can help a lot.

https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: the above mentioned tool says **Fail2ban scans log files (e.g. /var/log/apache/error_log) and bans IPs that show the malicious signs -- too many password failures, seeking for exploits, etc. Generally Fail2Ban is then used to update firewall rules to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time, although any arbitrary other action (e.g. sending an email) could also be configured. Out of the box Fail2Ban comes with filters for various services (apache, courier, ssh, etc). ** does it strictly not work with non-apache webservers?

Comment: If you go into the configs you'll see options for a very wide range of services it can monitor and act on. Lots of people use it for SSH but it works equally well for things like NGINX and other applications too. It's a great tool and no it's not Apache-only.